# IE 10 (desktop/IE Tab plugin) always timeout on "waiting for request" after 120 seconds

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer-10

I've recently installed Windows 8/IE10. I mostly use Chrome, which works fine since Day 1, but occasionally I need to visit legacy sites that require IE to function. Normally I use IE Tab plugin, but this time it didn't work. I then opened IE and it's the same: I can browse with Chrome but NOT with IE 10.

IE 10 seems to be stuck at "waiting for response" stage. I looked into this and found out that every single request-response took exactly 120 seconds. The rest of the header, response body, etc. seems fine, but there's ALWAYS this strange delay... This problem wasn't there before I installed Windows 8. Please don't blame the OS--I think it might be just some misconfiguration, but I haven't figured out WHAT yet.

A little note on my network environment: I'm behind my own router box(NAT), which is connected to floor LAN, which in turn has Internet access.